# MetadataCacheAttributeSource class

Tags: spring, weblogic12c, spring-modules

My application hosted on weblogic 12c server shows a stuck thread that is caused by attribute method of MetadataCacheAttributeSource class: 
at org.springmodules.cache.interceptor.MetadataCacheAttributeSource.attribute(MetadataCacheAttributeSource.java:53) 
The attribute method calls the get method of HashMap class: 
at java.util.HashMap.get(HashMap.java:303)

I believe this class is bundled with spring-modules-cache.jar.
Is a new version of this jar available with synchronized implementation of the HashMap ?